# Convergence for infinite sum of all primorials reciprocals.

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, infinity, products

I'm not math major, but I am interested in maths, and was at home thinking about primes, and thought about the quistion in the title. It might seem complex or kind of vague (I'm not a native english speaker), but I simply want to know if, and if so, what the equation below converges to: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k}\big)$$ Where $p_k$ is the k'th prime. (For example: $p_2=3$)

I have tried looking all over the internet and using different kinds of calculators to estimate it, and even trying to compute it manual.
My best guess is that converges to 1.

For if we take all natural numbers, and took away all multiples of 2, we would have taken half of all numbers. if we now did 3, we would have taken another sixth of all numbers away;

Since 3 is a factor of a third of numbers, but every second multiple of 3 is also a multiple of 2, we would have only take a sixth of all numbers away.

Continuing should correspond to the equation above, and we should have taking all natural numbers away in the end, since all natural numbers are a multiple of primes (except 1).

But it doesn't seem to converge to 1 when I try to compute it manually. I would appreciate some help from some real mathematicians

Comment: It should be clarified what your product notation means. Is it a product that runs over the $n$ terms associated with the first $n$ primes? Or is it a product that only runs over those primes less than or equal to $n$?

Comment: *sum of all products of reciprocal...* Do you want the sum or the product of their reciprocals?

Comment: The product of the reciprocals converges to $0$. If their sum converges it is (empircally) $> 3$. It certainly isn't $1$: just the first three primes' reciprocals $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5}$ sums to $1.033333$.

Comment: Are you referring to primorials? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) If so then it is easy to check that it holds  #$n \geq 1/n^2$ and there for the sum converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/$#$n \leq \frac{pi^2}{6}$

Comment: Are the primes in your products necessarily distinct? Or can there be repeated factors?

Comment: @Michael I mean the n terms associated with the first n primes, for example n=3 would be 2, 3, and 5. Such that we get the sum of 1/(2)+1/(2*3)+1/(2*3*5) and so on. But I'm not the best at notation.

Comment: Then you want to define $\{p_1, p_2, p_3,...\} = \{2, 3, 5, ...\}$ as the sequence of primes and you are interested in $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k}$$ This sum is between 0 and 1 because $$0\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$

Comment: Following the ink of @Dlexp it says this sum is approximately $.70523017...$.  It is easy to get upper and lower bounds that are both very close to $.70523017...$ by just evaluating the sum on the first 10 terms (this gives a lower bound) and then upper-bounding the (exponentially decaying) error $\sum_{n=11}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k}\leq \sum_{n=11}^{\infty}(1/2)^k = 1/1024$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer summarizes my comments. Let $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, ...\}=\{2, 3, 5, ...\}$ be the sequence of primes. We are interested in the number
$$ x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k}$$
Fix $m$ as a positive integer. We get
$$ \sum_{n=1}^m \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} \leq x \leq \sum_{n=1}^m \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} + \underbrace{\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} (1/2)^n}_{1/2^m}$$
which uses the fact that $\prod_{k=1}^n(1/p_k)\leq 1/2^n$ for all $n\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. So we can get an estimate to within an error $1/2^m$ just by evaluating the first $m$ terms of the sum. For $m=5$ we get
$$ \underbrace{\frac{543}{770}}_{0.705} \leq x \leq \underbrace{\frac{543}{770} + \frac{1}{2^5}}_{0.737}$$